# Apache 2.4 redirecting local virtual host to https instead http

Tags: linux, laravel, macos, apache, virtualhost

I'm using MAC os and apache 2.4. I have created a virtual host for my local development. This virtual host is redirecting to https instead of simple http (I need it to work in http). I have tried it on chrome and safari. It's a laravel project.

Here is the content of httpd-vhosts.conf

```
#    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/onboardera/public"
    ServerName onboardera.dev
    ServerAlias onboardera.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/multi-site/public"
    ServerName multi-site.dev
    ServerAlias multi-site.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Following is the content of hosts file.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       multi-site.dev
127.0.0.1       khan.multi-site.dev
127.0.0.1       onboardera.dev
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

[Screenshot is also attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMxk0.png)

Comment: You need to add open ssl

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.dev` domains belongs to google and Google Chrome is rolled out v63 that now forces all `.dev` domains to use HTTPS.

So either You can try some other browser or use `.local` or `.test`

Viable option is to switch to Firefox as your development browser. It’s fast, has comfortable dev tools, and has really made a ton of improvements over the past few years.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user set .test and call it without www like onboardera.test
I encountered this issue and did the above mentioned changes and it worked for me